# How would I fix elements moving due to an element animating above?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am getting an error with my website. I cannot seem to figure out why the 3 buttons below the title images are moving while the 2nd title picture is animating. My goal is to get the 3 buttons below the titles to stay where they are when the title2 is animating. The animation is a constant shrink/grow and is called pulse. Here is all of my code, its messy but this is just for me to learn.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Website</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/snow.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
body
{
background-color: black;
background-image: url("res/bg.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
div.button1
{
  width: 600px;
  position: static;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 30px 50px;
  background-image: url("res/button1.png");
  border: 1px solid #FF0030;
  border-radius: 55px;
  /*opacity:0.4;*/
  /*filter:alpha(opacity=40);*/
}
div.button2
{
  width: 600px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 30px 50px;
  background-image: url("res/button2.png");
  border: 1px solid #00B7FF;
  border-radius: 55px;
  /*opacity:0.4;*/
  /*filter:alpha(opacity=40);*/
}
div.button3
{
  width: 600px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 30px 50px;
  background-image: url("res/button3.png");
  border: 1px solid #00FFD5;
  border-radius: 55px;
  /*opacity:0.4;*/
  /*filter:alpha(opacity=40);*/
}
div.button1:hover
{
 transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
 -webkit-stroke-width: 5.3px;
 -webkit-stroke-color: #FFFFFF;
 -webkit-fill-color: #FFFFFF;
 box-shadow: 1px 0px 20px #000000;
 border: 2px solid #FF0030;
}
div.button2:hover
{
transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
 -webkit-stroke-width: 5.3px;
 -webkit-stroke-color: #FFFFFF;
 -webkit-fill-color: #FFFFFF;
 box-shadow: 1px 0px 20px #000000;
 border: 2px solid #00B7FF;
}
div.button3:hover
{
 transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
 -webkit-stroke-width: 5.3px;
 -webkit-stroke-color: #FFFFFF;
 -webkit-fill-color: #FFFFFF;
 box-shadow: 1px 0px 20px #000000;
 border: 2px solid #00FFD5;
}
#seventyfive{
    font-size:100px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<img src="res/title.png"</img>
<img id="seventyfive"; src="res/title2.png"</img>
</br>
<div class="button1">
</div>
<div class="button2">
</div>
<div class="button3">
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
<script>
$(document).ready( function(){
        $.fn.snow({ minSize: 8, maxSize: 15, newOn: 390, flakeColor: '#C800FF' });
});
(function pulse(back) {
    $('#seventyfive').animate(
        {
            'font-size': (back) ? '100px' : '160px',
            height: (back) ? "60%" : "50%",
            width: (back) ? "60%" : "50%",
            
            
        }, 700, function(){pulse(!back)});
})(false);
</script>
```

Thank you for reading my question, I am open to any answers/suggestions. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vertical placement is going to be based on the size of whatever is above the items. So, if the item above it is 100px, then the button below will be at position 100px + margin-bottom. When that item is 200px, the button below will start at 200px + margin-bottom.

What you want is a div around your image tag that doesn't change size.

```
<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
   <img id="seventyfive"; src="res/title2.png"</img>
</div>
```

PS, look into css animations vs. jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#seventyfive{
    font-size:100px;
    font-weight:bold;
    position:absolute;

}
```

I'm not making any promises on it. Tried to run it through a fiddle first, but the pulse wasn't working. If that doesn't work then you could also try
CSS

```
.seventyfive {
position:absolute;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="seventyfive">
<img src="res/title.png">
<img id="seventyfive"; src="res/title2.png">
</div>
```